# ConTeXt: \placeinitial to account for quotation mark

Tags: chapters, context, lettrine

## Background

In novels, a lettrine is typically a letter. When writing prose, sometimes chapters begin with an opening quotation mark.

## Problem

The quotation mark is stylized, rather than the first letter of the paragraph.

## Code

Consider:

```
\setuphead[chapter][
  after={\placeinitial},
  page=no,
]

\starttext
\chapter{Harriet Tubman}
"Every great dream begins with a dreamer. Always remember, you have within
you the strength, the patience, and the passion to reach for the stars to
change the world.
\chapter{Eleanor Roosevelt}
Great minds discuss ideas; average minds discuss events; small minds
discuss people.
\stoptext
```

This produces:

[image: quotation mark lettrine]

## Question

Without changing any text between `\starttext` and `\stoptext`, how would you change the `\placeinitial` macro to allow for changing the size and alignment of a quotation mark that is a chapter's first character---and format the first letter into a lettrine, as well?

## Related

See the following question for examples:

- [size and alignment of quotation mark with lettrine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/609544/2148)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, none of this is documented in https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupinitial. I had to find this out by reading the Lua source.

It looks like you cannot apply special formatting to the opening quote. There is just no code for it and since it is in Lua there is also no straightforward and easy way to hook into it. What is available though is skipping the quote by adding `first` to the methods (very intuitive...).

To request more features you will have to contact the mailing list.

```
\defineinitial[two][method={first,auto}]
\setuphead[chapter][
  after={\placeinitial[two]},
  page=no,
]

\starttext
\chapter{Harriet Tubman}
"Every great dream begins with a dreamer. Always remember, you have within
you the strength, the patience, and the passion to reach for the stars to
change the world.
\chapter{Eleanor Roosevelt}
Great minds discuss ideas; average minds discuss events; small minds
discuss people.
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Henri. I wish dropping the opening quote was an option. Good to know about `first`! I'll ping the mailing list.